# I have a laptop with Windows vista and when I try to connect to the local shared server asks me for password, when in other PCs there is no need

Tags: windows-vista, passwords, windows-98

I have a laptop with Windows Vista and when I try to connect to the local shared server asks me for password, when in other PCs there is no need for any password. If I install Windows 98 I already get access to the server with no password.

It runs on LAN, no wireless.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are trying to access a network share on another computer, and being asked repeatedly for credentials.

What you could try to do is stock the credentials, hopefully once and for all, this way :

1. Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts
2. Click "Manage you network passwords"
3. Click the Add button
4. Fill out the details of the computer to "Log on to", "User name" and "Password"
5. Ensure that the "Credential type" is "A Windows logon credential"
6. Click OK, then Close

You should do this while logged-in using your normal account.

Comment: thanks! that works.. now I'm still having another problem.. on this PC the network is very slow compared to other PCs, is this possible to make it faster? thanks

Comment: Many questions of this type were treated here. The stock answer is to ensure that your network-card driver is up-to-date (as from the manufacturer's website). If this doesn't help, post a new question, with all the details of your computer and network-card models.